# Algorithm to calculate sphere by revolution has addition error

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, geometry

I am trying to generate a sphere by revolution (rotation).
My idea is to rotate one point round an axis in equal steps until 180 degrees, so that I have a template.
Then I would rotate this template round another axis (in steps, up to 360 degrees) to generate a sphere.
The algorithm is as follows:

```
if (o == objeto::SPHERE_P) // if the object type is Template Sphere I will rotate only 180 degrees.
        ang = M_PI;

    Vertices.resize(tamanio);
    int p = 0;
    //
    //Rotamos en función del eje.
    float nrot = 1.0/nr;
    switch (e)
    {
    case eje::AXIS_X:
        for (int i = 0; i <= nr; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < nv; j++, p++)
            {
                float R = Distancia(plantilla[j], _vertex3f(plantilla[j].x, 0, 0));
                float a = R * cos(i*nrot*ang);
                float b = R * sin(i*nrot*ang);
                    Vertices[p] = _vertex3f(plantilla[j].x, a, b);
            }
        break;
    case eje::AXIS_Y:
        for (int i = 0; i <= nr; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < nv; j++, p++)
            {
                float R = Distancia(plantilla[j], _vertex3f(0, plantilla[j].y, 0));
                float a = R * cos(i*nrot*ang);
                float b = R * sin(i*nrot*ang);
                Vertices[p] = _vertex3f(a, plantilla[j].y, b);
            }
        break;
    case eje::AXIS_Z:
        for (int i = 0; i <= nr; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < nv; j++, p++)
            {
                float R = Distancia(plantilla[j], _vertex3f(0, 0, plantilla[j].z));
                float a = R * cos(i*nrot*ang);
                float b = R * sin(i*nrot*ang);
                Vertices[p] = _vertex3f(a, b, plantilla[j].z);
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

- **nr** is the number of rotations.
- **Distancia** is the sphere radius, or the distance from the origin to any point on the sphere.
- **a** and **b** are the coordinates (depending on the axis along which the sphere is rotated, one coordinate does not change)
- **nrot** is 1.0/nr
- **Vertices** is a vertex array
- **nv** holds the number of vertices

**The question**

Since I use `M_PI`, sphere generation involves a tiny numerical error, which eventually will result in a runtime error. The situation is that the last vertex should be *exactly* over the initial axis, but instead of that its coordinates are as in this image:
[They should be 0,-5,0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ishOq.png)
It is a small error, yet enough to make my function (that checks if a point is over an axis) fail.
I can fix it, rounding the vertex coordinates, but that feels to me  like a botched job.

Can anyone show me another way to generate the angles of rotation so that I can generate the sphere with no error?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the world of floating-point representation and truncation errors. Newer assume that in this context you can use comparisons for equality. Consider introducing a tolerance.

Comment: Does your C library provide the function `sinpi`?

Comment: Consider the simmetry, calculate only the points in 0 < angle < pi/4 and get the others by simple tranformation of coordinates.

Comment: It is an error to expect floating point computations to be exact.

Comment: Why don't you iterate over degree instead of radians, and then calculate the radians from that? This way, if your degree is a whole number, or at least one that can be accurately represented by a binary value, the only error happens when converting to radians, but not when summing up.

Answer (score 0):

A loop like

```
for (i= 0, th= 0; i <= n; i++, th+= π/n)
    s= sin(th);
```

cannot guarantee that the final value of `th` will be exactly `π`, and are we even sure that `sin(π) = 0` numerically ?

Safer to use

```
for (i= 0, th= 0; i <= n; i++, th+= π/n)
    s= i < n ? sin(th) : 0;
```

(In a similar vein, do not expect a loop that passes by `π/6` to yield exactly `sin(th) = 0.5`.)

Comment: Okay, I am aware that π/6  will not yield exactly sin(th) = 0.5, but there is no other way to get exactly sin(th) = 0.5? Even without using PI?  Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @dazckel: I don't know, but is this important ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem